# install flash player automatically with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

i need install flash player on IE when it's not installed.
Is a way to install plugins on IE withe pure JAVASCRIPT?
I think there is a solution in ACTIVEX but i couldn't find it ,

Comment: use a "no flash" display and move on...nothing you can do

Comment: If this was possible, there would be tons of viruses out there exploiting this very possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. There is no way that JavaScript can get out of the browser context to do this (not without exploiting some kind of loophole, which would be patched soon, hopefully!)